# Output piped command to variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'am trying to write a small script to create an JSON File. I have to store SSL Certificates inside this json, so i have to convert the CRT/KEY file to the required format.

Is there a Solution to store the result of:

```
cat $domain.key | sed s/$/\\n/ | tr -d '\n'
```

inside an Variable (bash.script)

```
input_key=`cat $domain.key | sed s/$/\\n/ | tr -d '\n'`
```

Does not run the "sed" after the cat (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do it:

```
input_key=$(cat ${domain}.key | sed 's/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n')
```

The `sed` is running in your example, but I believe something in the regex bits are getting interpreted by the shell. You simply need to wrap the regex in single quotes to avoid any shell interpretation. The following also works:

```
input_key=`cat ${domain}.key | sed 's/$/\\n/' | tr -d '\n'`
```

Comment: UUOC spotted !!

Comment: Useless use of `tr`, as well.

Comment: That is ! So what is improved version ?

Comment: `input_key=$(perl -pe 's!\n!!' ${domain}.key)`
    ;) Why `perl`? Why not, I say.

Comment: and a pure shell version ?

Comment: `blah=$(<${domain}.key); input_key=${blah//[[:space:]]/};`, although I guess that wouldn't work if the file had any whitespace. Wouldn't in this case given the material, but still not safe for general use. Pray tell, how would you do it shell-only?

Comment: Got it: `blah=$(<${domain}.key); input_key=${blah//$'\n'/};`